# Function: Input x value to return corresponding y value

Tags: r, function, plot

How is it possible to find a corresponding value on a plot in R?

```
cdf = function(x){
sample = rpois(1000, 50)
order(sample)
x=sample[order(sample)]
y=seq(0, 1, length.out=1000) #Effectively 1/n sequence
plot(x,y)
######  x= enter value of x, returns y value probability
}
```

So once I have entered the x value, it should calculate the corresponding probability.

Comment: Do you want something like this: ``plot(table(x))``? Then you can find your value e.g. with ``tx <- table(x)``, ``tx[which(names(tx)=="45")]``

Comment: If you want to find points on the plot by clicking on the plot itself, you can have a look at ``?identify``